# Upload file using FormData and jQuery.ajax.post

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

**when I upload a file using FormData() in IE 8/9 it shows the following error.** Please need help....

**Webpage error details**

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Wed, 23 Apr 2014 14:06:30 UTC

**Message: 'FormData' is undefined**
Line: 6
Char: 13
Code: 0

**MyCode:**

```
 $('#UploadImage').click(function () {
        var formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
        var filevalue = $('file').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/controller/action",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                $('#FileId').val(data);
                $('#file').val('');
                var msg = "You have successfully Uploaded a Image.";
                $("#Error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                $('#dialog').show();
                $('#DialogMessage').text(msg);
                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    buttons: {
                        "Yes": function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function (err) {
                if (status == "error") {
                    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                    alert(msg);
                    $("#Error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                }
            }
        });

    });
```

**Html Code:**

```
        <table class="dialogTable">
            <tr>
                <td><b>Select your file</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="gif|jpeg|bmp|png|jpg" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    <table>
        <tr>            
                <td>
                    <input type="button" id="UploadImage" value="Upload Image" />
                </td>
           </tr>
```

when I click UploadImage button in IE8 show the error in FormData()

Comment: You cannot upload files with AJAX, you have to use a different method. Here is a tutorial - http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1766159

Comment: @JayBlanchard can be uploaded...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JayBlanchard was partially correct.  While you can upload files via ajax in modern browsers, this does not include IE9 and older.  If you are using IE9 and older, you must create a form with a `<input type="file">` element that targets a hidden iframe, and then submit the form.  This will result in a file upload that does not redirect your main browsing context (window).